# C# Prevent child control from leaving main control WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, key, controls

I have a simple program that creates a few buttons and it allows you to move them around using custom class. Those buttons are added in a Panel and they should not be able to leave it. However i cant seem to make this while the left mouse button is still being held i.e im stopping the control at the edge of the panel bounds and disabling the draggable feature but it actually takes action once i release the mouse button. Here's the code :

```
private void CreateButtons(IList<Button> inputArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Count; i++)
        {
            inputArray[i] = new Button
            {
                Height = 100,
                Width = 100
            };
            PuzzelHolder.Controls.Add(inputArray[i]);
            inputArray[i].Text = Values[i].ToString();
            inputArray[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            inputArray[i].Draggable(true);
            inputArray[i].Location = new Point(20, 20);
            inputArray[i].MouseDown += Button_Mouse_Down;
            inputArray[i].MouseUp += Button_Mouse_Up;
            //horizontal += inputArray[i].Width;
        }
    }
```

This is how i create the buttons as you can see they have events associated with them :

```
    private void Button_Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsLeaving(((Control) sender), PuzzelHolder))
        {
            ((Control) sender).Location = new Point(((Control) sender).Location.X, ((Control) sender).Location.Y);
            ((Control) sender).Draggable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            ((Control) sender).Draggable(true);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Mouse_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).Draggable(true);
    }
```

And here's also the Draggable class :

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Control, bool> draggables =
               new Dictionary<Control, bool>();
    private static System.Drawing.Size mouseOffset;

    public static void Draggable(this Control control, bool Enable)
    {
        if (Enable)
        {
            // enable drag feature
            if (draggables.ContainsKey(control))
            {   // return if control is already draggable
                return;
            }
            // 'false' - initial state is 'not dragging'
            draggables.Add(control, false);

            // assign required event handlersnnn
            control.MouseDown += control_MouseDown;
            control.MouseUp += control_MouseUp;
            control.MouseMove += control_MouseMove;
        }
        else
        {
            // disable drag feature
            if (!draggables.ContainsKey(control))
            {  // return if control is not draggable
                return;
            }
            // remove event handlers
            control.MouseDown -= control_MouseDown;
            control.MouseUp -= control_MouseUp;
            control.MouseMove -= control_MouseMove;
            draggables.Remove(control);
        }
    }

    private static void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseOffset = new System.Drawing.Size(e.Location);
        // turning on dragging
        draggables[(Control)sender] = true;
    }

    private static void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // turning off dragging
        draggables[(Control)sender] = false;
    }

    private static void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // only if dragging is turned on
        if (draggables[(Control)sender])
        {
            // calculations of control's new position
            var newLocationOffset = e.Location - mouseOffset;
            ((Control)sender).Left += newLocationOffset.X;
            ((Control)sender).Top += newLocationOffset.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an MDI Container?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. it depends on the behaviour you want.

1.in this button is allowed to be dragged outside of form.

you can set main form property IsMdiContainer = true. and then by calculating relative position, set top and left of button  and manipulate using mouse up event.

```
        void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var btnDragged = ((Control)sender);
            var parent = btnDragged.Parent;
            if (btnDragged.Left  parent.Width) btnDragged.Left = parent.Width - btnDragged.Width;
            if (btnDragged.Bottom > (parent.Height - btnDragged.Height)) btnDragged.Top = parent.Height - btnDragged.Height * 2;
        }
```

if you don't want mdicontainer, then just replace parent variable with your main form name in above code.

2. if you don't want to allow buttons to be dragged outside. you could do same thing in mouse move event. but it will give you some flickering.
   you can also change the extension class to support this behaviour.

   ```
   static void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
           // only if dragging is turned on
           if (draggables[(Control)sender] == true)
           {
               var parent = ((Control)sender).Parent;
               System.Drawing.Point newLocationOffset = e.Location - mouseOffset;
               var controlDragged = (Control)sender;
               if ((controlDragged.Left + newLocationOffset.X) >= 0 && (controlDragged.Right + newLocationOffset.X) <= parent.Width && (controlDragged.Top + newLocationOffset.Y) >= 0 && (controlDragged.Bottom + newLocationOffset.Y) < (parent.Height - controlDragged.Height))
               {
                   controlDragged.Left += newLocationOffset.X;
                   controlDragged.Top += newLocationOffset.Y;               
               }
           }
    }
   ```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the response im currently using the second option which doesn't allow the controls to go outside, but is there anyway that i can reduce the flickering ? It's awful